How can I improve my Keras based CNN's training and testing accuracy for fundus image classification?
``I've been working on creating a diabetic retinopathy classification model using a fundus image set of 400 images (from MESSIDOR) with gradings from 0-3 (4 classes). I've tried changing my model architecture, complexity, output features, using augmentation, dropout, and regularizers, but my model accuracy for training and validation just can't seem to get past the 50% mark.
Here is my code:'`
#split data into the training and validation set X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42, test_size=0.2, stratify=y)
#defining model structure 
model = Sequential()

#conv layers
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(250, 250, 3), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))#output filters was 32)
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
#dense layers
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.45))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

`**# compile the model
**`opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

`**# Data augmentation
**`datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=30,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)

history = model.fit(datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size= 2), epochs=30, validation_data
(X_test, y_test), shuffle=True)

model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)



Results of accuracy and loss in images attached[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/dgbal.png)

I've reviewed your code, and to improve test accuracy, use batch normalization
layers, perform hyperparameter tuning using Keras Tuner, and, if possible,
increasing the size of the dataset. These  will help enhance the model's performance.
